# gerrit push error (internal error)--setGroups(List<String>) only valid before creating change

Tags: git, gerrit

When I push a commit to gerrit server, it reports

[image]

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1532/1532)
remote: Counting objects: 3678, done
remote: Processing changes: new: 1, done    
remote: error: internal error
To ssh://192.168.110.165:29418/t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5
 ! [remote rejected]         HEAD -> refs/for/t0522_master (internal error)
错误：无法推送一些引用到 'ssh://192.168.110.165:29418/t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5'
```

Then, when we open the error log in the gerrit server, it shows:

```
[ReceiveCommits-1[java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@202caac[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@8faa1dc[Wrapped task = com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContextAwareRunnable@63d4eb3]]]-for-SSH git-receive-pack /t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5 (scm)] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.hooks.HookFactory : hooks.path: /home/xc-buildsrv/.gerrit/reviewsite/hooks [CONTEXT RECEIVE_ID="t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5-1681863158615-78cb22ee" project="t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5" request="GIT_RECEIVE" ]
[2023-04-19T08:12:38.776+08:00] [ReceiveCommits-1[java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@202caac[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@8faa1dc[Wrapped task = com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContextAwareRunnable@63d4eb3]]]-for-SSH git-receive-pack /t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5 (scm)] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.hooks.HookFactory : hooks.commitReceivedHook resolved to /home/xc-buildsrv/.gerrit/reviewsite/hooks/commit-received [CONTEXT RECEIVE_ID="t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5-1681863158615-78cb22ee" project="t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5" request="GIT_RECEIVE" ]
[2023-04-19T08:12:38.837+08:00] [ReceiveCommits-1[java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@202caac[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@8faa1dc[Wrapped task = com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContextAwareRunnable@63d4eb3]]]-for-SSH git-receive-pack /t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5 (scm)] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.hooks.HookFactory : hooks.refUpdatedHook resolved to /home/xc-buildsrv/.gerrit/reviewsite/hooks/ref-updated [CONTEXT RECEIVE_ID="t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5-1681863158615-78cb22ee" project="t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5" request="GIT_RECEIVE" ]
[2023-04-19T08:12:39.105+08:00] [ReceiveCommits-1[java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@202caac[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@8faa1dc[Wrapped task = com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContextAwareRunnable@63d4eb3]]]-for-SSH git-receive-pack /t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5 (scm)] WARN  com.google.gerrit.server.update.RetryHelper : CHANGE_UPDATE was attempted 2 times [CONTEXT RECEIVE_ID="t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5-1681863158615-78cb22ee" project="t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5" request="GIT_RECEIVE" ]
[2023-04-19T08:12:39.609+08:00] [SSH git-receive-pack /t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5 (scm)] WARN  com.google.gerrit.server.git.MultiProgressMonitor : MultiProgressMonitor worker did not call end() before returning
[2023-04-19T08:12:39.610+08:00] [SSH git-receive-pack /t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5 (scm)] ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.git.receive.AsyncReceiveCommits : error while processing push
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.gerrit.exceptions.StorageException: Can't insert change/patch set for t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.receive.AsyncReceiveCommits.preReceive(AsyncReceiveCommits.java:407)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.receive.AsyncReceiveCommits.lambda$asHook$0(AsyncReceiveCommits.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceivePack.service(ReceivePack.java:2268)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceivePack.receive(ReceivePack.java:2182)
    at com.google.gerrit.sshd.commands.Receive.runImpl(Receive.java:98)
    at com.google.gerrit.sshd.AbstractGitCommand.service(AbstractGitCommand.java:109)
    at com.google.gerrit.sshd.AbstractGitCommand$1.run(AbstractGitCommand.java:74)
    at com.google.gerrit.sshd.BaseCommand$TaskThunk.run(BaseCommand.java:492)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContextAwareRunnable.run(LoggingContextAwareRunnable.java:113)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.WorkQueue$Task.run(WorkQueue.java:612)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.google.gerrit.exceptions.StorageException: Can't insert change/patch set for t-alps-release-r0.mp1-V5
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.receive.ReceiveCommits.insertChangesAndPatchSets(ReceiveCommits.java:1133)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.receive.ReceiveCommits.processCommandsUnsafe(ReceiveCommits.java:798)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.receive.ReceiveCommits.processCommands(ReceiveCommits.java:684)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.receive.AsyncReceiveCommits.lambda$preReceive$2(AsyncReceiveCommits.java:386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator.lambda$cleanup$1(RequestScopePropagator.java:186)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator.lambda$context$0(RequestScopePropagator.java:174)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.ThreadLocalRequestScopePropagator.lambda$wrapImpl$0(ThreadLocalRequestScopePropagator.java:45)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$1.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:85)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$2.run(RequestScopePropagator.java:116)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.google.gerrit.extensions.restapi.RestApiException: Error inserting change/patchset
    at com.google.gerrit.extensions.restapi.RestApiException.wrap(RestApiException.java:25)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.receive.ReceiveCommits.asRestApiException(ReceiveCommits.java:322)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.receive.ReceiveCommits$CreateRequest.addOps(ReceiveCommits.java:2809)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.receive.ReceiveCommits.lambda$insertChangesAndPatchSets$21(ReceiveCommits.java:1081)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.update.RetryableChangeAction.lambda$new$0(RetryableChangeAction.java:48)
    at com.github.rholder.retry.AttemptTimeLimiters$NoAttemptTimeLimit.call(AttemptTimeLimiters.java:78)
    at com.github.rholder.retry.Retryer.call(Retryer.java:160)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.update.RetryHelper.executeWithTimeoutCount(RetryHelper.java:564)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.update.RetryHelper.execute(RetryHelper.java:507)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.update.RetryableAction.call(RetryableAction.java:173)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.update.RetryableChangeAction.call(RetryableChangeAction.java:84)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.receive.ReceiveCommits.insertChangesAndPatchSets(ReceiveCommits.java:1125)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: setGroups(List<String>) only valid before creating change
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:508)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.change.ChangeInserter.setGroups(ChangeInserter.java:309)
    at com.google.gerrit.server.git.receive.ReceiveCommits$CreateRequest.addOps(ReceiveCommits.java:2752)
    ... 27 more



i want it push success
```